# Почему мой Blender не может работать с Collada (.dae) файлами?

Tags: blender

Вот так это выглядит у меня:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А так должно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Xubuntu v16.04 Blender v2.76 (пробовал и официальный репозиторий, и launchpad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение на англоязычном форуме. Как оказалось, репозитории Ubuntu по непонятным причинам не включают в себя аддон для поддержки этого формата. Нужно качать [официальный релиз](https://www.blender.org/download/).